# Using an ArrayAdapter with LiveData.

Tags: android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I'm familiar with MVVM in WPF, but am in the process of porting an existing Android app to make use of a ViewModel class and LiveData for the first time.

The app "as/was" has a custom ArrayAdapter that is used to correctly display the items contained in a List in a gridview. The code that does that looks essentially like this ("essentially" because there are actually 4 such grids in the activity that all do it like this):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> playerAdapter = new MyAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.grid_item, playerList);

gridView.setAdapter(playerAdapter)
```

and when the playerList contents changed, there was an explicit call to

```
playerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Since my goal is to have the grid respond automatically when the playerList changes, and never have to notify anything, it seems now that the "playerList" needs to become a `MutableLiveData<List<String>>`.

I suspect I am going to have a problem though-

The MyAdapter class extends `ArrayAdapter<T>`

So in practice it's going to become an

```
ArrayAdapter<MutableLiveData<List<String>>>
```

But a MutableLiveData isn't going to work there, right?

I could unwrap it and make the call to create it look like this:

> ```
> ArrayAdapter<String> playerAdapter = 
> new MyAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.grid_item, playerList.getValue());
> ```

Is this correct? It seems the way of madness.

Ultimately my goal is to just assign the gridView's `android:adapter` property to this thing in xml and never have to think about it anymore (beyond the required calls to setvalue() and postValue() when I modify the underlying list...which I'm not even sure how would work here.

I would hope there's already a MutableLiveData Collection that's ready to go somewhere and I'd use that.

What the standard way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the way you are thinking is wrong. Don't worry about this:

```
ArrayAdapter<MutableLiveData<List<String>>>
```

You will get a list thats all. MutableLiveData is to set a livedata object like setValue() or postValue() manually. Just set your below code whenever liveData gets triggered and gives you the new playerList, something like this:

```
viewModel.getPlayListObservable().observe(this, new Observer<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<String> playerList) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> playerAdapter = new MyAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.grid_item, playerList);
            gridView.setAdapter(playerAdapter);
            playerAdapter.notifydataChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: So to confirm I get this: PlayerListObservable would be the MutableLiveData of the List<String> and I'd have a method observe changes to that which would set the contents of the GridView? So the GridView and Mutable List<String> actually are unaware of one another?

Comment: I believe that the last line should be playerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); no?

Comment: yes..i will change it. Actually we dont need that as you are setting the adapter in before line. Regarding your 1st comment, yes GridView and Mutable List<String> are unaware of each other as they will be in different layers (if you want to follow architectural pattern). Mutable List<String> will be in ViewModel where as GridView is in View.

Comment: This will cost you a lot of memory - initializing a new adapter every time a new list is received. Also, you dont need to notify the adapter after changing the adapter.

Comment: I agree that was just for an example, ideally the first 2 lines of initializing and setting adapter should be outside the observable. If there is change in the list then get the appropriate list and use notifydatachanged()